django-haystack elasticsearch spanish special chars (accents)
I'm using Django-haystack 3.3.0 over Django 4.x, and use Elasticsearch 7.17.24 as backend.
I'm dealing with texts in Spanish, so for example I'm index the text:
El corazón del mar

And when I'm trying to search:
corazon

I got 0 results, but when I'm search
corazón or Corazón.
I got n results; n>0.
Any idea?

If you are using English Analyzer, corazon and corazón are different.Corazón will be normalized to corazon before searching.
You can use Spanish Analyzer or similarity query to solve this problem.
